# OOM when using placeholder for is_training when use slim BN

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

I set a placeholder to is_training params in `slim.batch_norm` like this:

```
is_traing_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
output = slim.batch_norm(
            input,
            activation_fn=activation_fn,
            is_training=is_training_ph,
            updates_collections=None,
            scale=scale,
            scope=scope)
```

Feed it like this:

```
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={is_training_ph:False}
```

when I feed is_training_ph with True, the program is OK, But when I feed is_traing_ph with False, the program throws OOM error.

And, when I do not use placeholder like this:

```
    output = slim.batch_norm(
            input,
            activation_fn=activation_fn,
            is_training=True,
            updates_collections=None,
            scale=scale,
            scope=scope)
```

it is not any problems.

Here is my full test code and log trace:
https://gist.github.com/xxxzhi/8fc8f840a8ec07fdbae7c2fc2c77b3da

Does anyone know the reason? Is it a bug of `slim.batch_norm`?

The memory of GPU is 12G. 
CUDA 8, tensorflow1.2, tensorflow1.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be that slim.batch_norm uses more memory when is_training is set to False, because the gradient computation is different (when is_training is false) and thus uses a different implementation. Could you decrease the batch size by half to see if it is working?

Comment: @Yao Zhang, It is ok when I increase memory or decrease the batch size. In fact, I want to ask why the memory is increase when using placeholder and feed with false. I have modify the Question.

Comment: @Yao Zhang, When I do not use placeholder, It is ok.

Comment: The problem is about placeholder, but about if you set is_training to True or False in slim.batch_norm. I suspect, if setting is_training to False in slim.batch_norm, the underlying implementation of batch_norm's gradient computation uses more memory.

Comment: @Yao Zhang, Why batch_norm's gradient gradient computation uses more memory when feed with False? In fact, I think the computation should use less memory because there are no more need of calculating moving mean/moving variance.

Comment: Please see this for details: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10857, This this PR will potentially reduce the memory usage: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/12580